# Knowing a function while only knowing its partial derivatives?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

So again we study a physics course without studying mathematics course

We are in the work energy chapter , and I'd like to know if you can know the function $f(x,y,z)$ if you know all of its partial derivatives everywhere?

Like $f(x,y,z)$ and we have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}  = 5x, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2y, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 8$$

Comment: Do you know the partial derivatives everywhere or just at one point?

Comment: There's always a constant which the partial derivatives never "see".

Comment: Do you mean $df/dz=8$?

Comment: yes i mean that ,can you know the function by knowing these derivs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=5x \implies f=\frac{5}{2}x^2+g(y,z)$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 2y \implies g=y^2+h(z)$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial z}=\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial z} = 8 \implies h=8z+c$

Then by substituting together, $f(x,y,z)=\frac{5}{2}x^2+y^2+8z+c$

So apparently you'll need to know the value of $f$ somewhere to completely recover it, but if you're doing this in a physics course, I'm sure you'll have boundary conditions to make things physically meaningful which you can use.

Answer (score 2):

Basically if $f$ satisfy the mixed derivatives condition, i.e.:

$$\frac{d^2f}{dx dy} = \frac{d^2f}{dy dx}$$

And similarly for $x, z$ and $y, z$, then yes in your situation (i.e. smooth function and "contractible" domain).

This is due to the Poincare Lemma.